# How do you reuse UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios

Here is my problem. I display an imagePicker modally and snap a photo. I then push to a "review" screen where the user can add notes to it. If the user taps back on the navigation button, the camera controller reappears but it's "frozen". I can't take any new photos or cancel out of it.

Is there a way to reuse the image picker?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you dismiss the UIImagePickerController before moving to the review screen.

Swift 3

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]!)
{

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

If you have declared UIImagePickerController as a global variable, you will be able to reuse it without any problem. Hope this helps